# Render element and caching

Tags: caching, theming

I'm a little bit confused with [hide()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/hide/7) documentation.
It says:

> The first time render() or drupal_render() is called on an element
>   tree, as each element in the tree is rendered, it is marked with a
>   "#printed" flag **and the rendered children of the element are cached**. **Subsequent calls to** render() or **drupal_render()** will not traverse the
>   child tree of this element again: they will **just use the cached**
>   children. So if you want to hide an element, be sure to call hide() on
>   the element before its parent tree is rendered for the first time, as
>   it will have no effect on subsequent renderings of the parent tree.

First of all, I want to say I understand that hide() allow to avoid rendering of a specific element.

But documentation says more :

1. By talking about caching element as it is the default behaviour. For me, if #cache property is not defined for an element, when rendering the element will be not be cached.
2. And for me also, **subsequent calls to drupal_render()** will not use the cached element, because *#printed* property will be checked before trying to get the cached element (#printed=TRUE means return '';) .

I want to get your explanation about this.

Answer (score 1):

Render arrays are trees. If you `hide()` the subtree `P1.P2.P3.P4`, it's stil possible for a supertree (`P1.P2` or `P1.P2.P3`) to have caching enabled (i.e. have `#cache` set).

Also note that just having `#cache` set does not mean that the subtree with that element as a root does not get cached per se. Only when `#cache[keys]` is set is render caching triggered. `#cache` can also just contain cacheability metadata (tags, contexts, max-age) describing the cacheability of that subtree.

See https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/render/arrays/cacheability.

Comment: Thank, but I still use Drupal 7..
On another hand, i don't understand your answer,which doesn't answer really my 2 points. For example hide() documentation seems to say that caching is the normal  (default) behaviour when render an element tree. Try to read hide() documentation for Drupal 7.

Comment: Oh, Drupal 7. Pretty much nothing in Drupal 7 uses render caching. It may not be worth bothering.

Comment: Note that the explanation I gave is for the overall algorithm/render pipeline and applies to D7 too.